# Disable options in an appended drop-down list using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu, append, yii2

I am using Yii2 php framework and here's how I displayed the first drop-down list:

```
<?php 
    $deductions = PayrollItems::find()->where(['store_id' => $session['store_id']])->orwhere(['store_id' => null])->where(['payroll_type' => 'Deduction'])->all();
    $deductionslistData = ArrayHelper::map($deductions,'payroll_items_id', 'payroll_name');
    echo $form->field($model2, 'deduction_item_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => $deductionslistData,
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a Deduction ', 'id' => 'deduction_item'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
    ]);
?>
```

Here is the script function for appending a new drop-down list:

```
function addDeductionItem(){   
    var count = $('#count2').val();
    if($('#deduction_item').val()=="" || $('#deduction_item_' + count).val()==""){
        alert("Please fill in the earning item field first!");
    }
    else{
        count++ ;
        $('#count2').val(count);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?r=payslip/deductions',
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {},
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("#deduction_item_" + count).append($("<option></option>").html(""));
                //$("#deduction_item_" + count).append($("<option></option>").val('add item').html("Add New Item"));
                for(i=0; i<data.length;i++)
                {                      
                    $("#deduction_item_" + count).append($("<option></option>").val(data[i][1]).html(data[i][0]));                        
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('An error occured!');
                alert('Error in ajax request');
            }
        });

        var deduction = '<tr id="row_' + count +'"><td><select class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Select a Deduction " style="width: 100%; cursor: pointer;" data-krajee-select2="select2_6789bf5d" tabindex="-1" id="deduction_item_' + count + '" name="deduction_item_' + count + '"></select></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="deduction_unit_' + count + '"  name="deduction_unit_' + count + '"></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="deduction_amount_' + count + '" name="deduction_amount_' + count + '" onchange="_getTotalDeduction(id)"></td>';

        deduction += '<td><a style="cursor:pointer" class="ibtnDel"><i class="fa fa-times">&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></td></tr>';    

        $("#deduction_items").append(deduction);

        $("#deduction_items").on('click','.ibtnDel',function(){
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });

        $('#row_' + count + ' select').select2(); 
    }        
}
```

I have a drop-down list, say for example it has 3 options, then I select option 01. Now, when I append a new drop-down list (by clicking the button "Add Deduction Item" in my case), option 01 in the appended drop-down list will be disabled.

The whole thought is, when I select an option in the first drop-down list, that selected option should be now disabled in the appended drop-down list, and so on.

I have searched this problem over the internet. I found some but they just don't work for me because my problem is not really similar to those I found.

I found and tried this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rajan222000/yww8apn9/1/
But still don't work for me. I noticed it has static number of drop-down lists. I tried `var deductionID = 'deduction_item_' + count + '';` to make it dynamic, but I don't know why it doesn't work.

I really need your help with this.

Comment: can you explain this to me more clearly: `When I select an option in the first drop-down list, that selected option should be now disabled in the appended drop-down list, and so on.`

Comment: I have a drop-down list, say for example it has 3 options, then I select option 01. Now, when I append a new drop-down list (by clicking the button "Add Deduction Item" in my case), option 01 in the appended drop-down list will be disabled.

Comment: so, it does not work if it is not included in the new dropdown list, right?

Comment: what do you mean does not work? you mean disabled? it won't work anymore since it will be disabled.

Comment: Let' user choose the item A in the first dropdownlist and in the second dropdowlist you want the item A to be displayed but user should not be able to choose it, is that right? I suggested what if we totally do not include item A in the second dropdown list?

Comment: sorry I got confused, I got it now. your fiddle example is working, but it is not working in your computer?

Comment: yes you get it right. I have also considered that not including anymore a selected option but I guess disabling is much better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74674/discussion-between-kaynewilder-and-erkaner).

Comment: hello. I would just like to know if you already have some updates?

Comment: in your scenario, each time you click the button, we just need to create a second (or third) copy of the first dropdownlist with the same items listed, is that right? We just need to disable the items that were selected in other dropdownlists? So, we need just one ajax call, right? If ıt is okay, we can generate three dropdownlists at the same time and hide the last two. When the first is selected, then we can show the second one, etc. What do you think_

Comment: Is this still not solved?
In my case i was using same drop-down on 10 places. On select of 1st drop-down i was hiding that option from other drop-down and if this option un selected i was showing that option in other dropdown.

Comment: Was i right about the what you want?

Comment: yes. since my dropdown is inside a table's `<tr><td></td></tr>`, if I add a new dropdown, then remove it again, the dropdown list gets updated of course.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly then you need to fetch all of the selected values of already generated drop-downs and disable it in the newly created drop-down.

Without any code refactoring you need to start a simple for loop and disable all the selected values in the new drop-down.

Adding this to the end of the success function in the Ajax call should do the trick:

```
for(var c=count-1; c>=0; c--) {
    var sel = $("#deduction_item_" + c).val();
    $("#deduction_item_" + count).find("option[value'"+sel+"']").prop('disabled', true);
}
```